# Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, json, wcf, linq-to-sql, automapper

Could somebody please explain what this error means? I have used automapper onces before but never had this kind of error.

**Error**

The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping. Mapping types: Char -> QuestionDto System.Char -> CollectiveDistributedPolling.QuestionDto Destination path: QuestionDto.Question1.Question1.Question10[0] Source value: R'.

**Service1.svc.cs**

```
public Service1() {
    Mapper.CreateMap<Question, QuestionDto>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<QuestionDto, Question>();
}

private Question MapToQuestion(QuestionDto q)
{
       return Mapper.Map<QuestionDto, Question>(q);
}

private QuestionDto MapToQuestionDto(Question q) <<< EXCEPTION GETS THROWN HERE
{
       return Mapper.Map<Question, QuestionDto>(q);
}

public QuestionDto ThrowQuestion(string user)
{
       return MapToQuestionDto(Database.GetInstance().ThrowQuestion(user));
}
```

**IService1.cs**

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        QuestionDto ThrowQuestion(String user);

[DataContract]
    public class QuestionDto
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int next { get; set; }   
        [DataMember]
        public String question { get; set; }   
        [DataMember]
        public ICollection<QuestionDto> QuestionPhrase { get; set; } 
        [DataMember]
        public QuestionDto Next{ get; set; } 
        [DataMember]
        public ICollection<QuestionAnswerDto> QuestionAnswer { get; set; } 
        [DataMember]
        public ICollection<UserAnswerDto> UserAnswer { get; set; } 
    }
```

**Question.cs**

```
    public partial class Question
    {
        public Question()
        {
            this.QuestionPhrase = new HashSet<Question>();
            this.QuestionAnswer = new HashSet<QuestionAnswer>();
            this.UserAnswer = new HashSet<UserAnswer>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string question { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> next { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Question> QuestionPhrase { get; set; }
        public virtual Question Next { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<QuestionAnswer> QuestionAnswer { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserAnswer> UserAnswer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Thanks to danludwig I could pinpoint the problem. It has something to do with

```
[DataMember]
public QuestionDto Next{ get; set; }
```

But that mapping seems fine to me

Comment: Please post your `Question` class. Are there any properties on either object of type `char`?

Comment: @danludwig Posted the Question class, but there is no char type in there

Comment: You can check with Mapper.DynamicMap<> instead.

Answer (score 5):

This basically means AutoMapper is missing information about how to map from one property to another.

Though I can't tell by looking at the error, you can try the following process to figure out which property is missing the mapping. Start out by ignoring all of your destination type's properties:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Question, QuestionDto>()
    .ForMember(d => d.ID, o => o.Ignore())
    .ForMember(d => d.next, o => o.Ignore())
    .ForMember(d => d.question, o => o.Ignore())
    .ForMember(d => d.QuestionPhrase, o => o.Ignore())
    .ForMember(d => d.Next, o => o.Ignore())
    .ForMember(d => d.QuestionAnswer, o => o.Ignore())
    .ForMember(d => d.UserAnswer, o => o.Ignore())
    // also ignore any other properties
;
```

Then, one by one, uncomment the ForMember lines until your exception is raised again. That is the property AM can't figure out how to map. I suspect is is in one of your collection properties...

**Update**

I'm wondering if perhaps there is a recursion problem going on here. Try this:

```
.ForMember(d => d.Next, o => o.ResolveUsing(s => {
    var tryToMap = Mapper.Map<QuestionDto>(s.Next); // exception here???
    return null;
}));
```

Not saying you have a data problem here, but if you did, you should expect AM to throw. If your `question.Next == question`, I imagine that AM would overflow the stack trying to map a property to it's owner over and over again.

Comment: Great tip!

I had to change
 
`[DataMember]
public Question Next{ get; set; }`

To

`[DataMember]
public QuestionDto Next{ get; set; }`

Comment: The error started again.

I ran your "tests" and its definitely `.ForMember(d => d.Next, o => o.Ignore())`

Comment: Ok good, is it the same exact error, or is it a little different? I wonder if AM might be having issues with mapping nested references to the same type. You might need a custom ResolveUsing() delegate for that one. The `Next` doesn't by any chance reference the same instance of `Question`, does it?

Comment: Question(next) has a foreign key to Question(ID) and LINQ makes 2 reference objects QuestionPhase and Next which I don't really understand why...  One of then is probably referencing the same instance like you suggested. Could I just delete one in the Model.edmx?

Comment: Without knowing anything about your data or business domain, I am not going to tell you what to delete. Especially since I don't use EF with edmx files, at least for the past 4 years or so.

Comment: After some fiddling I got 
Int32 -> QuestionDto
System.Int32 -> CollectiveDistributedPolling.QuestionDto
Destination path:
QuestionDto.Next.Next