# Automapper 6.0. Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I've already seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618670/missing-type-map-configuration-or-unsupported-mapping), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677889/automapper-missing-type-map-configuration-or-unsupported-mapping) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119476/automapper-exception-missing-type-map-configuration-or-unsupported-mapping).

And I've got this exception when I move from `Automapper 3.3.1.0` to `Automapper 6.0.1.0`. This code throws no exception in `Automapper 3.3.1.0`.

I have 2 class :

Class 1 : (Domain)

```
public class Movie:IEntityBase
{
    public Movie()
    {
        Stocks = new List<Stock>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
    public string Director { get; set; }
    public string Writer { get; set; }
    public string Producer { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public byte Rating { get; set; }
    public string TrailerURI { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }
}
```

Class 2 :

```
public class MovieViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public string Director { get; set; }
    public string Writer { get; set; }
    public string Producer { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public byte Rating { get; set; }
    public string TrailerURI { get; set; }
    public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfStocks { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var validator = new MovieViewModelValidator();
        var result = validator.Validate(this);
        return result.Errors.Select(item => new ValidationResult(item.ErrorMessage, new[] { item.PropertyName }));
    }
}
```

I've tried to map in constructor of a class cause `Automapper 6.0.1.0` does not have method `Configure()` to override:

```
public class DomainToViewModelMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public override string ProfileName
    {
        get { return "DomainToViewModelMappings"; }
    }

    public DomainToViewModelMappingProfile()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
           cfg.CreateMap<Genre, GenreViewModel>()
                    .ForMember(vm => vm.NumberOfMovies, map => map.MapFrom(g => g.Movies.Count()));

           cfg.CreateMap<Movie, MovieViewModel>()
             .ForMember(vm => vm.Genre, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Genre.Name))
             .ForMember(vm => vm.GenreId, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Genre.ID))
             .ForMember(vm => vm.IsAvailable, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Stocks.Any(s => s.IsAvailable)))
             .ForMember(vm => vm.NumberOfStocks, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Stocks.Count))
             .ForMember(vm => vm.Image, map => map.MapFrom(m => string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Image) == true ? "unknown.jpg" : m.Image));
        });                
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
     }            
  }
```

And I've got the following exception:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: Movie -> MovieViewModel HomeCinema.Entities.Movie ->
>   HomeCinema.Web.Models.MovieViewModel

I've tried to figure out what property is a reason of this exception through `Ignore()` method, however, I still get the above exception.

```
 cfg.CreateMap<Genre, GenreViewModel>()
                    .ForMember(vm => vm.NumberOfMovies, map => map.MapFrom(g => g.Movies.Count()));

 cfg.CreateMap<Movie, MovieViewModel>()
    .ForMember(vm => vm.Genre, map => map.Ignore())
    .ForMember(vm => vm.GenreId, map => map.Ignore())
    .ForMember(vm => vm.IsAvailable, map => map.Ignore())
    .ForMember(vm => vm.NumberOfStocks, map => map.Ignore())
    .ForMember(vm => vm.Image, map => map.Ignore());
```

Forgot to say that I am calling the following method in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
```

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The most interesting point that this code is valid in `AutoMapper 3.3.1.0`.

**Update:**

It works!:) Thanks to all you, guys, and special thanks to @AndriiLitvinov. The work code:

```
public class DomainToViewModelMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public override string ProfileName
    {
        get { return "DomainToViewModelMappings"; }
    }

    public DomainToViewModelMappingProfile()
    {

        CreateMap<Genre, GenreViewModel>()
                    .ForMember(vm => vm.NumberOfMovies, map => map.MapFrom(g => g.Movies.Count()));

        CreateMap<Movie, MovieViewModel>()
         .ForMember(vm => vm.Genre, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Genre.Name))
         .ForMember(vm => vm.GenreId, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Genre.ID))
         .ForMember(vm => vm.IsAvailable, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Stocks.Any(s => s.IsAvailable)))
         .ForMember(vm => vm.NumberOfStocks, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Stocks.Count))
         .ForMember(vm => vm.Image, map => map.MapFrom(m => string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Image) == true ? "unknown.jpg" : m.Image));
     }
}
```

and call `Initialize()` just one time:

```
//Global.asax.cs
protected void Application_Start()
{
   var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

   AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
   WebApiConfig.Register(config);
   Bootstrapper.Run();
   RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
   GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();
   BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}

public class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.AddProfile<DomainToViewModelMappingProfile>();
        });
    }
}

public class Bootstrapper
{
    public static void `Run()
    {
        //Configure Autofac
        AutofacWebapiConfig.Initialize(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

        //Configure Automapper
        AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have tried to implement such mapping locally and it all worked. I assume that you have many profiles that all call `Mapper.Initialize` as far as I remember it is meant to be called only once at application startup and all the profiles should call [CreateMap method](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/5.0-Upgrade-Guide):

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Foo, Bar>();
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, but what do you mean by "having many profiles"? I have just one class `class DomainToViewModelMappingProfile : Profile`.

Comment: I mean many classes that drive from `Profile` which in turn call `Mapper.Initialize`.

Comment: I rewritten my code and I am calling just one time this method `Initialize()`. Please, see my **Update** section.

Comment: Looks correct now. Do you still get same exception?

Comment: Now I have another exception: `Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with appropriate configuration. If you are trying to use mapper instances through a container or otherwise, make sure you do not have any calls to the static Mapper.Map methods`. Maybe you know the root of the exception. I double checked that I do not call static methods of `Mapper`.

Comment: I get same exception when I call `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid` before `Mapper.Initialize`. Make sure you call things in right order.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are really cool! It works! Could you tell me, please, what was the reason of that?

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad it helped. I had similar issue while upgrading to v5. The reason of your initial issue was that you didn't register mappings in the fist call to Initialize and second call didn't make any effect. And the second issue was that Initialize was not called at all before you tries to validate configuration. I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` method you must make sure that each and every property has a valid source and target to map. If you do not have valid source and target for each property you get an error. If you look at the error message in fact it will tell you in detail. I just skimmed through your code but for example `public virtual ICollection<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }` does not have a mapping.

Comment: this code is valid in `AutoMapper 3.3.1.0` without mapping `Stocks`.

Comment: @StepUp I am glad your worked out your problem. There has been a great deal of change from version 3 to 6. You should not expect it to work at every version. For example, from what I can tell you are using static API of AutoMapper and at some point (I guess version 5.x) static API completely got discarded and came back at a later time.